# Multiple pagination in a tab content

Tags: javascript, laravel, pagination, tabs, eloquent

I have a tab fields. These are contain years. 
I need to show paginate numbers for all of them separately. 
For example i have;

All - 2018 - 2017 - 2016

2018 tab has contain 30 value. 2017 tab = 15 value. 2016 tab = 15 value. 
All tabs has contain = 60 value.

When i clicked random tabs, paginate number must change.

Tabs:

```
<ul id="tab">
<li>All</li>
<li>2018</li>
<li>2017</li>
</ul>
```

inside the tab:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="contents">
    @foreach($projects as $project)
    <div>{{$project->created_at}}</div>
    <div><img src="{{('/storage/'.$project->image)}}"/></div>
    @endforeach
</div>
<div class="contents">
    @foreach($projects2018 as $project)
        <div>{{$project->created_at}}</div>
        <div><img src="{{('/storage/'.$project->image)}}"/></div>
    @endforeach
</div>
<div class="contents">
    @foreach($projects2017 as $project)
        <div>{{$project->created_at}}</div>
        <div><img src="{{('/storage/'.$project->image)}}"/></div>
    @endforeach
</div>
<div class="contents">
    @foreach($projects2016 as $project)
    <div>{{$project->created_at}}</div>
    <div><img src="{{('/storage/'.$project->image)}}"/></div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

I made this `.contents` field.

With my script codes. Tabs are changing and values are coming.
This is my controller:

```
$projects = Project::latest()->paginate(50);
    $projects2018 = Project::whereYear('created_at', '=', 2018)->paginate(50);
    $projects2017 = Project::whereYear('created_at', '=', 2017)->paginate(50);
    $projects2016 = Project::whereYear('created_at', '=', 2016)->paginate(50);
```

In this situation controllers just get 50 value. After that js paginate these 50 value. 10 by 10. I mean 5 there is 5 pages. But all values are downloading same time. I need download page 2-3-4-5 values when clicked. Not download all values same time! This is so boring. I can't figure out how to make.

Also this is my javascript code.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{

    $("#tab").tabpager({
        items: 10,
        contents: 'contents',
        time: 300,
        previous: 'Geri',
        next: 'İleri',
        start: 1,
        position: 'top',
        scroll: true
    });
});
```

Still wondering the solution...

Answer (score 0):

Laravel by default, resolve the current page using get parameter `page`, ie `example.com/?page=3` this request, the paginator will resolve the current page to page 3.

These behaviours can be changed, when you look at the [declaration of `paginate` method](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L492):

```
public function paginate($perPage = null, $columns = ['*'], $pageName = 'page', $page = null)
```

You can create your own paginate approach for example, by changing the third parameter:

```
$projects2017 = Project::whereYear('created_at', '=', 2017)
    ->paginate(50, ['*'], 'p2017');
$projects2016 = Project::whereYear('created_at', '=', 2016)
    ->paginate(50, ['*'], 'p2016');
```

And this request, `example.com/?p2017=2&p2016=3` will then query the second page of project 2017 and the third page of project 2016.

Or another approach, with the same output, explicitly specify the page by fourth parameter:

```
$projects2017 = Project::whereYear('created_at', '=', 2017)
    ->paginate(50, ['*'], 'page', 2);
$projects2016 = Project::whereYear('created_at', '=', 2016)
    ->paginate(50, ['*'], 'page', 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

To complement Ben's answer. After adding our own pagination parameters in our controller.

```
$projects2017 = Project::whereYear('created_at', '=', 2017)
    ->paginate(50, ['*'], 'p2017');
$projects2016 = Project::whereYear('created_at', '=', 2016)
    ->paginate(50, ['*'], 'p2016');
```

In our view `projects.blade.php` instead of use `{{$projects2017->render()}}` use

```
{{$projects2017->appends(["p2016" => $projects2016->currentPage()]->links())}}
```

And viceversa so when you change page on one tab it saves the current page of the other and the link will look something like `example.com/?p2017=1&p2016=2`

I tried this in **Lavarel 5.7** and it works!!